# Sum of specific values when specific key are equivalent in Ruby

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

here is my problem, i'm developing a web app with Ruby On Rails and I'm stuck on a specific query

I have table `purchase_item` which contains: `user_id`, `item_id`, `amount`, `total, ...`

I want sum of amount and total when `user_id` AND `item_id` are the same.

so here:

```
@purchase_items = PurchaseItem.all
@purchase_items = ?
```

Comment: have you tried any query?

Comment: I tried with some select, merge ... but each time i'm getting error

Comment: then post your query

Comment: will you pass user_id and item_id?

Comment: no it's inside the table

Answer (score 0):

Try below query :

```
PurchaseItem.select("SUM(purchase_items.amount) AS total_amount, SUM(purchase_items.total) AS total_value").where("user_id = ? AND item_id =?", user_id, item_id ).group(:user_id)
```

This might work for you.

Comment: This looks like what i tried but i can't use the where clause because the user_id and item_id is inside the table purchase_item.

Lines need to be sum only if   purchase_item 1 has the same user_id and item_id than purchase_item 2 , ....

Comment: For that you can group by two columns `PurchaseItem.group([:user_id, :item_id]).select("SUM(purchase_items.amount) AS total_amount, SUM(purchase_items.total) AS total_value")`or `PurchaseItem.group([:user_id, :item_id]).sum(:amount, :total)`

Comment: Still not working i tried another way. Now i've : 

[{"item"=>31, "amount"=>1, "total"=>#<BigDecimal:7fe0eafe6a50,'0.4591E2',18(18)>, "user"=>25},
{"item"=>31, "amount"=>1, "total"=>#<BigDecimal:7fe0f1c98748,'0.4591E2',18(18)>, "user"=>25}]

which I need to be : 

[{"item"=>31, "amount"=>amount1+amount2, "total"=>total1+total2, "user"=>25}]

Comment: yes because one user can buy same item multiple times which are stored in different purchase

Comment: have you tried `PurchaseItem.group([:user_id, :item_id]).select("SUM(purchase_items.amount) AS total_amount, SUM(purchase_items.total) AS total_value")`

Comment: yes i receive : #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<PurchaseItem id: nil>, #<PurchaseItem id: nil>, #<PurchaseItem id: nil>, #<PurchaseItem id: nil>, #<PurchaseItem id: nil>, #<PurchaseItem id: nil>, #<PurchaseItem id: nil>]>

Comment: There is any solution to sum hash in array with a condition ?  It should be easier than the query i'm looking for no ?

Comment: No the way you want is achievable easily but because of lack of data on my machin I am not able to test query. Still if you want to go for hash way there are many function in ruby by which you can achive this. But still I suggest you to open rails console and try things

Answer (score 0):

Try like that:--

```
amount = PurchaseItem.where("user_id = ? and item_id = ?", user_id,item_id).sum("amount")
total = PurchaseItem.where("user_id = ? and item_id = ?", user_id,item_id).sum("total")
```